# C# display result of a post to an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, iframe, dynamic

HI

I am perfoming a post in c# using this method.

```
  string post1(string url, string postdata)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);
        var x = byteArray.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


        string resp = (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
       return(responseFromServer);

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

where postdata is like

```
string postData = "login=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("xxxxxx") +
            //            "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("yyyyy");
```

The response i get back is some html.

NOw the problem is i want to show the request in an iframe but i have no clue as to how to do so..

Also is this the right way to do a post and show the page in an iframe or should i look at something differen.. ? Im using asp.net 3.5 and c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why this needs to happen inside of an iframe?  Also, what page event is triggering this?  A post-back, an AJAX call, etc.?

I get the feeling that any attempt to shove this off to an iframe is going to be ugly because an iframe is by design a different resource request.  So, given the information we have so far, I'd say that the "best" way to put this in an iframe would be to have two pages, the parent page and the framed page.  The framed page would make this request, possibly on `Page_Load`, and display the results as its entire response.

But then the question becomes how to get to that page the data that it needs.  In all likelihood the parent page has that data when it's being rendered, correct?  If that's the case then you could include it on the query string for the iframe's `src` and then read it from the query string on the framed page.